# How do I convert JSON content to HTML?

Tags: html, json, xslt

I was given a .json file with test questions. I need to convert them to HTML format. Below are examples of the json code I was given and how I need to get that content to look in HTML.

I'm not sure where to get started with the XSLT scripting process.

This is one question from the .json file:

```
{
                    "qNo": 24,
                    "uAnswer": "",
                    "question": "<p>Kathy knits sweaters and scarves, and she sells them online. She sells her scarves for $18 and her sweaters for $75. In January 2015, Kathy sold 40 items for a total of $1,461. How many more scarves than sweaters did Kathy sell that month?<\/p>",
                    "option": [
                        {
                            "strike": "false",
                            "data": "<p>13<\/p>",
                            "middle": "false"
                        },
                        {
                            "strike": "false",
                            "data": "<p>14<\/p>",
                            "middle": "false"
                        },
                        {
                            "strike": "false",
                            "data": "<p>15<\/p>",
                            "middle": "false"
                        },
                        {
                            "strike": "false",
                            "data": "<p>16<\/p>",
                            "middle": "false"
                        }
                    ],
                    "correct": 1,
                    "explanation": "<p><span fontWeight=\"bold\">Answer: B<\/span><\/p>\n<br><p>Let <span style='font-family: times_new_roman_italic;font-style: italic;'>x<\/span> and <span fontStyle=\"italic\">y<\/span> represent the number of scarves and sweaters Kathy sold, respectively:<\/p>\n<p lineHeight=\"36\"style = 'padding-left: 50px'><tab/><span style='font-family: times_new_roman_italic;font-style: italic;'>x<\/span> + <span fontStyle=\"italic\">y<\/span> = 40 and 18<span style='font-family: times_new_roman_italic;font-style: italic;'>x<\/span> + 75<span fontStyle=\"italic\">y<\/span> = 1,461<\/p>\n<p lineHeight=\"36\">Multiplying the first equation by 18 gives 18<span style='font-family: times_new_roman_italic;font-style: italic;'>x<\/span> + 18<span fontStyle=\"italic\">y<\/span> = 720. <\/p>\n<p lineHeight=\"36\">Subtracting 18<span style='font-family: times_new_roman_italic;font-style: italic;'>x<\/span> + 18<span fontStyle=\"italic\">y<\/span> = 720 from 18<span style='font-family: times_new_roman_italic;font-style: italic;'>x<\/span> + 75<span fontStyle=\"italic\">y<\/span> = 1,461 gives 57<span fontStyle=\"italic\">y<\/span> = 741, and so <span fontStyle=\"italic\">y<\/span> = 741 ÷ 57 = 13. <\/p>\n<p lineHeight=\"36\">So in January 2015, Kathy sold 13 sweaters and 40 − 13 = 27 scarves. <\/p>\n<p lineHeight=\"36\">Finally, she sold 27 − 13 = 14 more scarves than sweaters.<\/p>\n<p/>\n<\/br><\/br><p>**If you want to avoid the algebra, you can just reason it out. Assume Kathy sold 20 scarves and 20 sweaters. <br>Then she would have earned (20 × $18) + (20 × $75) = $1,860, which is $1,860 − $1,461 = $399 more than she actually earned. Reducing the number of sweaters by 1 and increasing the number of scarves by 1 reduces her earnings by $75 − $18 = $57. <br>Since 599 ÷ 57 = 7, <g breakOpportunity=\"none\">she sold 20 − 7 = 13 sweaters and 20 + 7 = 27 scarves.<\/g><\/p>"
                },
```

This is how I need to get it to look in HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" enumeration="" designation="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/css/main.css" />
        <link href="../../assets/css/main.css" title="default" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <title>Blank Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section typeof="ktp:Section" class="ktp-section">
            <section class="ktp-section-meta">
                <h1 property="ktp:title">Test or Section Title</h1>
                <span property="ktp:testName" class="ktp-meta">[add value]</span>
                <span property="ktp:sectionType" class="ktp-meta">[add value]</span>
                <span property="ktp:contentType" class="ktp-meta">assessment</span>
            </section>
            <ol property="ktp:questionSet" typeof="ktp:QuestionSet" class="ktp-question-set">
                <li class="ktp-question-set-meta">
                    <span property="ktp:questionSetType" class="ktp-meta">container</span>
                </li>
                <li property="ktp:question" typeof="ktp:Question" class="ktp-question">
                    <section class="ktp-question-meta">
                        <span property="ktp:interactionType" class="ktp-meta">single-select</span>
                    </section>
                    <section class="ktp-question-stem">
                        <p>Kathy knits sweaters and scarves, and she sells them online. She sells her scarves for $18 and her sweaters for $75. In January 2015, Kathy sold 40 items for a total of $1,461. How many more scarves than sweaters did Kathy sell that month?</p>
                    </section>
                    <ol class="ktp-answer-set">
                        <li property="ktp:answer" typeof="ktp:AnswerCorrect">13</li>
                        <li property="ktp:answer" typeof="ktp:Answer">14</li>
                        <li property="ktp:answer" typeof="ktp:Answer">15</li>
                        <li property="ktp:answer" typeof="ktp:Answer">16</li>
                    </ol>
                    <section property="ktp:feedback" class="ktp-feedback">
                        <p><b>Answer: B</b></p>
                        <p>Let <i>x</i> and <i>y</i> represent the number of scarves and sweaters Kathy sold, respectively:</p>
                        <p><i>x</i> + <i>y</i> = 40 and 18<i>x</i> + 75<i>y</i> = 1,461</p>
                        <p>Multiplying the first equation by 18 gives 18<i>x</i> + 18<i>y</i> = 720.</p>
                        <p>Subtracting 18<i>x</i> + 18<i>y</i> = 720 from 18<i>x</i> + 75<i>y</i> = 1,461 gives 57<i>y</i> = 741, and so <i>y</i> = 741 &#247; 57 = 13.</p>
                        <p>So in January 2015, Kathy sold 13 sweaters and 40 &#8722; 13 = 27 scarves.</p>
                        <p>Finally, she sold 27 &#8722; 13 = 14 more scarves than sweaters.</p>
                        <p>**If you want to avoid the algebra, you can just reason it out. Assume Kathy sold 20 scarves and 20 sweaters.</p>
                        <p>Then she would have earned (20 &#215; $18) + (20 &#215; $75) = $1,860, which is $1,860 &#8722; $1,461 = $399 more than she actually earned. Reducing the number of sweaters by 1 and increasing the number of scarves by 1 reduces her earnings by $75 &#8722; $18 = $57.</p>
                        <p>Since 599 &#247; 57 = 7, she sold 20 &#8722; 7 = 13 sweaters and 20 + 7 = 27 scarves.</p>
                    </section>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p class="place-top">Test or Section End: Place content above this line</p>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any guidance on how I can get started would be most appreciated.

Comment: XSLT transforms XML to XML, that's all it does. You must first obtain an XML version of your JSON.

Comment: XSLT 3 has two ways to transform/process JSON, you can use `parse-json` or `json-doc` and deal with XPath 3.1 maps and arrays or you can use `json-to-xml` and then transform the XML representation of the JSON like you would transform other XML. https://youtu.be/Hd5W6IpDA8Y?t=185 has one example of the first approach. https://youtu.be/1LHoMhEFagA?t=259 also has examples.  Those videos are based on the support in two of the mayor XML IDEs but of course the concepts apply in general to XSLT 3, whether you use any of those IDEs or a standalone XSLT 3 processor like Saxon 9.8 or 9.9.

Answer (score 1):

(I'm puzzled by all these strange attributes like `enumeration` and `designation`, but as that's not really pertinent I'll ignore my puzzlement).

Assuming XSLT 3.0, you could do something like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="data" select="json-doc('input.json')"/>

<xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" enumeration="" designation="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/css/main.css" />
        <link href="../../assets/css/main.css" title="default" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <title>Blank Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section typeof="ktp:Section" class="ktp-section">
            <section class="ktp-section-meta">
                <h1 property="ktp:title">Test or Section Title</h1>
                <span property="ktp:testName" class="ktp-meta">[add value]</span>
                <span property="ktp:sectionType" class="ktp-meta">[add value]</span>
                <span property="ktp:contentType" class="ktp-meta">assessment</span>
            </section>
            <ol property="ktp:questionSet" typeof="ktp:QuestionSet" class="ktp-question-set">
                <li class="ktp-question-set-meta">
                    <span property="ktp:questionSetType" class="ktp-meta">container</span>
                </li>
                <li property="ktp:question" typeof="ktp:Question" class="ktp-question">
                    <section class="ktp-question-meta">
                        <span property="ktp:interactionType" class="ktp-meta">single-select</span>
                    </section>
                    <section class="ktp-question-stem">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="parse-xml($data?question)"/>
                    </section>
                    <ol class="ktp-answer-set">
                        <xsl:for-each select="$data?option?*">
                          <li property="ktp:answer" typeof="{if (position()=$data?correct) then 'ktp:AnswerCorrect' else 'ktp:Answer'}">{string(parse-xml(?data))}</li>
                    </ol>
                    <section property="ktp:feedback" class="ktp-feedback">
                        <p><b>Answer: B</b></p>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="parse-xml($data?explanation)"/>
                    </section>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p class="place-top">Test or Section End: Place content above this line</p>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
```